# In Rust generic trait implementation, how to avoid "the type parameter `T1` is not constrained" when I only need TypeId from T1?

Tags: generics, rust, ioc-container, typeid

I'm learning Rust and experimenting with `TypeId`. I'm looking to see if it is possible to make a simplistic IoC container with it for Dependency Injection, but I've hit a problem with generic trait implementation for a function:

```rust
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};

trait IocInjectable<T> {
   fn get_injectables_list(&self) -> Vec<TypeId>;
   
   fn inject(&mut self, injectables: Vec<&dyn Any>) -> T;
}

impl<Func, T1, T2, TRet> IocInjectable<TRet> for Func
where
    Func: Fn(&T1, &T2) -> TRet + 'static,
    T1: 'static, // not sure, what goes here?
    T2: 'static
{
    fn get_injectables_list(&self) -> Vec<TypeId> {
        return vec![TypeId::of::<T1>(), TypeId::of::<T2>()];
    }

    fn inject(&mut self, injectables: Vec<&dyn Any>) -> TRet {
        let arg1 = injectables[0].downcast_ref::<T1>().unwrap(); 
        let arg2 = injectables[1].downcast_ref::<T2>().unwrap();
        return self(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T1` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/lib.rs:9:12
  |
9 | impl<Func, T1, T2, TRet> IocInjectable<TRet> for Func
  |            ^^ unconstrained type parameter
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5eedf114f2bc2c54e8960551f3f25ee)

Is there any way to make this approach with a function generically?

**Update** After reviewing answers for linked questions, I was able to solve compiler errors. Mind you, this is not optimal/final/good solution, this just solves the compiler error.

```rust
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};

trait IocInjectable<TArgs> {

    type TRet;

    fn get_injectables_list(&self) -> Vec<TypeId>;

    fn inject(&mut self, injectables: Vec<&dyn Any>) -> Self::TRet;
}

impl<Func, T1, T2, TRet1> IocInjectable<(T1, T2)> for Func
where
    Func: Fn(&T1, &T2) -> TRet1 + 'static,
    T1: 'static,
    T2: 'static
{
    type TRet = TRet1;

    fn get_injectables_list(&self) -> Vec<TypeId> {
        return vec![TypeId::of::<T1>(), TypeId::of::<T2>()];
    }

    fn inject(&mut self, injectables: Vec<&dyn Any>) -> TRet1 {
        let arg1 = injectables[0].downcast_ref::<T1>().unwrap(); 
        let arg2 = injectables[1].downcast_ref::<T2>().unwrap();
        return self(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c140d7b9d91c6de4e25f508634adda7)

Comment: Why do you need `TypeId` at all? Is it just so you can show a list of types for debugging purposes?

Comment: `TypeId` is used in `HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>` to store and retrieve injectables. But also, this is a learning exercise to better understand Rust ;-)

Comment: See also [RFC 447](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0447-no-unused-impl-parameters.md) and [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25041).